# calling replace method on system.array

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm new to the .Net World and Powershell. I have the following code:

```
$e = "A","A","A","B","A","B","A","A"

write-output $e.Replace("B", "C")
```

it works and prints

```
A
A
A
C
A
C
A
A
```

But I cannot find a Replace Method for system.array only for system.string. Why is it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement is working because you're running PowerShell v3 or newer. In PowerShell v3 Microsoft added a feature called [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/), which makes PowerShell invoke a method or property on all elements of an array if the array object itself doesn't have such a method or property.

If you run PowerShell v2 (e.g. by invoking `powershell.exe -version 2`) and run your code in that instance you'll get the following error:

```
Replace : Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain
a method named 'Replace'.
At line:1 char:24
+ write-output $e.Replace <<<< ("B", "C")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the "Write-Output"-part. But it works because you replace strings within the array for other strings.

Let me demonstrate:

```
$e = "A","A","A","B","A","B","A","A"
foreach($obj in $e){
    $obj.GetType()
}
```

This outputs (only posted first 2 lines):

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                                                                                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```